# Want to double the size of the stack when it becomes full

Tags: java, data-structures

```
package stack;

public class StackOperations {

private int top;
private int array[] = new int[10];

StackOperations()
{
    top = -1;
}

public void push(int item)
{
    if(top >= array.length)
    {
        System.out.print("Please wait. . .Resizing Stack");
        int arr[] = new int[2*array.length];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = arr; 
        array[++top] = item;
    }
    else
    {
        array[++top] = item;
    }                   
}

boolean IsEmpty()
{
    return top==-1?true:false;
}

public void pop()
{
    if(IsEmpty())
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    else
     top--;
}

public void display()
{
    if(IsEmpty())
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Stack");
        for(int i = top;i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            System.out.println( array[i]);
        }
    }       
}
}
```

What is wrong with my `push` method? When `top` is greater than or equal to `array.length` I want to double the size of the stack. But it is giving me an error which says "out of bounds" when I pushed greater than 10 elements onto the  stack. What is going wrong? any help would be appreciated

Comment: @happs, it's not quite correct, `array = arr` sets `array` field of `StackOperations` instance to the reference to the `arr` array.

Comment: You rather compare it with **`top==array.length-1`, ultimately for an array of 10 elements, maximum index could be 9**

Comment: Side note: any reason your `pop` returns void instead of popping an int off the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you compare `top` to `array.length` but then you assign `array[++top]`, the index is greater by one. When `top` is `array.length - 1` it's still less than `array.length`, therefore `else` branch is chosen, but `++top` is out of bounds.

Comment: Is there any shorter way to double the size of stack than mine?

Comment: @sony, yes, consider [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) method to double the array size. The usage is `array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);`

Answer (score 3):

The top index goes from 0 to 9. So just adjust your if condition like this, and you should be good to go.

```
 if (top >= array.length -1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Its going out of bounds.
Change the function to this.

```
   if(top == array.length - 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Please wait. . .Resizing Stack");
            int arr[] = new int[2*array.length];
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = array[i];
            }
            array = arr; 
            array[++top] = item;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your `if` statement doesn't work. If you changed `top` to `size`, then you would have been less likely to fall into this error.

In addition, your code can be cleaned up as follows:

- Copy the array using `Arrays.copyOf` (Java 6+)
- Don't repeat the `array[++top] = item` statement
- `expr ? true : false` is the same as `expr`
- The stack can be displayed, but you can't get a value back.

Updated code:

```
package stack;

public class StackOperations {

    private int size;
    private int array[] = new int[10];

    StackOperations()
    {
    }

    public void push(int item)
    {
        if (this.size == this.array.length)
        {
            this.array = Arrays.copyOf(this.array, this.size * 2); 
        }
        this.array[this.size++] = item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (this.size == 0);
    }

    public int pop()
    {
        if (this.size == 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty");
        return this.array[--this.size];
    }

    public void display()
    {
        if (this.size == 0)
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Stack");
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I changed `pop` to return the value popped off the stack. You could also implement a `peek` to see the value on top of the stack. As your code was, you could add values, but it was a black hole (other than `display`).